# PouchDB data is not persisted on iOS Cordova app after new install

Tags: ios, cordova, pouchdb, cordova-ios

The PouchDB data is getting remove after my Cordova base app is "hard" close .

Here are the steps :

1. Install the app
2. save some data in PouchDB name test
3. verify that the data is saved
4. close the app (on iOS double click the hone button)
5. reopen the app
6. Verify that saved lost

This only happen on the first install

As a test I created two button on a form with a sample code

```
$scope.saveme=function(){
       var db =new PouchDB("test");
       var todo = {
         _id: new Date().toISOString(),
         title: "test",
         completed: false
       };
       db.put(todo, function callback(err, result) {
         if (!err) {
            alert('Successfully posted a todo!');
         }
         else{
            alert(err);
         }
      });
    }



$scope.showme = function(){

   var db =new PouchDB("test");
   db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) 
      {
          alert(JSON.stringify(doc));
      });
     }
```

ios version: 4.5.4
cordova :6.5
pouch : 6.4.1

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IOS delete localstorage for his internal cleaning policy, this issue also may be happend in Android 6+ platforms.

Try to use this plugin, to persist localstorage info in sharedPreferences on IOS platform.

[Cordova persist localStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-persist-localstorage)

[Git Repository](https://github.com/alexcondrea/cordova-plugin-persist-localstorage)

Comment: Thanks... but I am using Pouch DB to persist my data and the data is only remove from pouch  after  first install only and the user double click the home button

Comment: I have the same problem, i change my login like a component, since then i have this problem, i don't founded a solution for that.